# Question about Bitwise Shift in Microsoft C++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, integer-promotion

I am doing the following bitwise shift in Microsoft C++:

```
uint8_t arr[3] = {255, 255, 255};
uint8_t value = (arr[1] << 4) >> 4;
```

The result of these operations confused me quite a bit:

```
value = 255
```

However, if I do the bitwise shift separately:

```
value = (arr[i] << 4);
value = value >> 4;
```

the answer is different and makes much sense:

```
value = 15
```

Can someone explain to me why this happens? I am familiar with the concepts of bitwise shift, or so I believed...

Thanks in advance!

(P.S.: It seems `g++` will have the same behavior. I am probably missing some important concepts with bitwise shift. Any help is greatly appreciated!)

Comment: duplicates: [Unexepected behavior from multiple bitwise shifts on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25393058/995714), [Why does combining two shifts of a uint8_t produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22702091/995714), [Why does it make a difference if left and right shift are used together in one expression or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61958789/995714)

Comment: Yeah, it does! I really wish I could find that post earlier.. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression `(arr[1] << 4)` will implicitly promote the value of `arr[1]` to type `unsigned int` before applying the shift operation, such that the "intermediate" result will not "loose" any bits (cf, for example, the explanation in [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)).

However, when you write `value = (arr[i] << 4);`, then this "intermediate" result will be converted back to `uint_8`, and in this step bits get cut off.

See the difference when you write `uint8_t value = ((uint8_t)(arr[1] << 4)) >> 4;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and linked documentation!

Answer (score 2):

In this expression with shift operators

```
(arr[1] << 4) >> 4;
```

there is used the *integral promotions*. That is the operand `arr[1]` is promoted to an object of the type `int` and such an object can store the result of the expression `arr[i] << 4`.

From the C++ 14 Standard (5.8 Shift operators, p.#1)

> ...The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and
> integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of
> the promoted left operand. The behavior is undefined if the right
> operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of
> the promoted left operand.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint8_t x = 255;

    std::cout << "std::is_same_v<decltype( x << 4 ), int> is "
              << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same_v<decltype( x << 4 ), int> << '\n';

    std::cout << "x << 4 = " << ( x << 4 ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
std::is_same_v<decltype( x << 4 ), int> is true
x << 4 = 4080
```

As for this code snippet

```
value = (arr[i] << 4);
value = value >> 4;
```

then in the first assignment statement the result of the shift operation is truncated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well! Your explanation and the marked one are equally good, and I really wish I could mark both solutions.